# How to order in XSLT?

Tags: xml, xslt

I need to order my XSLT.

Example:

```
<td>
<xsl:variable name="Type">
    <xsl:value-of select="/Rows/Row[@Group = $group and (@Type_Typ_x='Type1' or @Type_Typ_x='Type2')]/@Type_Typ_x"/>
</xsl:variable>

<xsl:value-of select="/Rows/Row[@Group = $group and (@Type_Typ_x='Type1' or @Type_Typ_x='Type2')]@Title" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
```

I would like to display only the Type 1 and if not, display the Type2.
Can anyone help me?

Sorry for my english.
Thank you so much...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the 'Type1' if it exists, you simply do this

```
<xsl:value-of select="Rows/Row[@Type_Typ_x='Type1']/@Title" />
```

And to get the 'Type2' if 'Type1' does not exist, you can do this

```
<xsl:value-of select="Rows[not(Row[@Type_Typ_x='Type1'])]/Row[@Type_Typ_x='Type2']/@Title" />
```

So, you could just put these two statements one after the other as only one will ever return a value. Alternatively you could combine like so:

```
<xsl:value-of select="Rows/Row[@Type_Typ_x='Type1']/@Title
                      |Rows[not(Row[@Type_Typ_x='Type1'])]/Row[@Type_Typ_x='Type2']/@Title" />
```

Another approach could be to use an **xsl:choose** statement

```
<xsl:choose>
   <xsl:when test="Rows/Row[@Type_Typ_x='Type1']">
       <xsl:value-of select="Rows/Row[@Type_Typ_x='Type1']/@Title" />
   </xsl:when>
   <xsl:when test="Rows/Row[@Type_Typ_x='Type2']">
       <xsl:value-of select="Rows/Row[@Type_Typ_x='Type2']/@Title" />
   </xsl:when>
</xsl:choose>
```

As soon as one **xsl:when** is found to be true, the others will not be evaluated, whether they are true or not.

Finally, if you could guarantee that 'Type1' records always came before 'Type2' records in the XML, then this would work:

```
<xsl:value-of select="Rows/Row[@Type_Typ_x='Type1' or @Type_Typ_x='Type2'][1]/@Title"/>
```

Comment: Tim,
Thank you very much. It worked! Thank you, thank you, thank you!
You're right and I resolve that problem with your explanation! I wish I can help you one day! 
Thank you!